# .htaccess Rewrite virtual subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a site that uses virtual paths, which worked great. I have added virtual subdomains to the site and everything still works except for a non-virtual subfolder...

The setup is simple enough:

```
www.sitename.com -> Main site
www.sitename.com/madeupfolder/ -> Virtual Folder
www.sitename.com/realfolder/ -> Folder on the server
```

I was using this before the virtual folders:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^backoffice/(.*)$ realfolder/index.php?uri=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

I changed that to this to make the virtual folders work:

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|gif|jpg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=$1&hostName=%{HTTP_HOST} [L]
```

The virtual folders work now, but when trying to get to the backoffice I get an Internal Error... I've tried putting in the backoffice line, and at one point that folder worked, but the rest of the site didn't...

Comment: Look in your error log to find out more specifics about the 500 internal server error. Probably it is a redirect loop.

Comment: You are correct, the internal error is caused by a redirect loop... Any ideas on how I can fix this?